# SSIS Flat File with Numeric DataType with Spaces

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm using SSIS to load a fixed length Flat File into SQL.

I have a weight field that has been giving me trouble all day.
It has a length of 8 with 6 DECIMAL POSITIONS IMPLIED (99V990099).

The problem i'm having is when it isn't populated and has 8 spaces.

Everything i try gets an error:

"Invalid character value for cast specification"."
OR
"Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
OR
Data conversion failed. 
The data conversion for column "REL_WEIGHT" returned status value 2 and status text 
"The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

I've tried declaring it as DT_String & DT_Numeric.

I've tried many variations of:

```
TRIM([REL_WEIGHT])=="" ? (DT_STR,8,1252)NULL(DT_STR,8,1252) : REL_WEIGHT

ISNULL([REL_WEIGHT]) || TRIM([REL_WEIGHT]) == "" ? (DT_NUMERIC,8,6)0 : (DT_NUMERIC,8,6)[REL_WEIGHT]

TRIM(REL_WEIGHT) == "" ? (DT_NUMERIC,8,6)0 : (DT_NUMERIC,8,6)REL_WEIGHT
```

But nothing seems to work.

Please someone out there have the fix for this!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be running afoul of the following point, explained nicely at http://vsteamsystemcentral.com/cs21/blogs/applied_business_intelligence/archive/2009/02/01/ssis-expression-language-and-the-derived-column-transformation.aspx:

> You can add a DT_STR Cast statement to the expression for the MiddleName, but it doesn't change the Data Type. Why can't we change the data type for existing columns in the Derived Column transformation? We're replacing the values, not changing the data type. Is it impossible to change the data type of an existing column in the Derived Column? Let's put it this way: It is not possible to convert the data type of a column when you are merely replacing the value. You can, however, accomplish the same goal by creating a new column in the Data Flow.

I've solved this on past occasions by loading the data from the flat file as strings, and then deriving a new column in a Derived Column transformation which is of numeric type. You can then perform the appropriate trimming, validation, casting, etc. in the SSIS expression for that new column in the transformation.

Here, I found an example SSIS expression I used at one point to derive a time value from a 4-digit string:

```
(ISNULL(Last_Update_Time__orig) || TRIM(Last_Update_Time__orig) == "") ? NULL(DT_DBTIME2,0) : (DT_DBTIME2,0)(SUBSTRING(TRIM(Last_Update_Time__orig),1,2)+":"+SUBSTRING(TRIM(Last_Update_Time__orig),3,2)+":00")
```

Comment: I have created 2 new columns in my SQL table.  1 as Char(8) and 1 as INT along with the Column already there as Decimal(8,6).  So everything i try i have a place to load everything every which way to find something that works.

Comment: When you say "the column already there as Decimal(8,6)", do you mean you've loaded the flat file data using the destination data types, i.e. decimal for the `REL_WEIGHT` column? That's not correct; you have to load it as a string type, because you have to validate it before you convert it to decimal.

Comment: IIRC, the Flat File Connection Manager Editor is where you configure the initial load types. You have to set them to strings in that editor. Referring to the example code I pasted into my answer, I initially loaded the column (named `Last_Update_Time__orig`) from the flat file as a DT_STR, and then the code derived the new column (named it `Last_Update_Time`) as a DT_DBTIME2.

Comment: My latest attempt is to bring it in as a String - Create a Derived Column with an expression "TRIM(REL_WEIGHT) == "" ? (DT_STR,9,1252)"0.0000000" : (DT_STR,9,1252)(LEFT(REL_WEIGHT,2) + "." + RIGHT(REL_WEIGHT,6))".    THEN Have it go through a Data Transformation Task to convert it from Unicode to String or eventually -Numeric

Comment: The column Decimal(8,6) is there "In my SQL table design"  But nothing is being mapped there currently.  So I have 3 test destination fields set up 1 with the correct Decimal(8,6), 1 as char(9) (to fit the decimal) & 1 as INT (to test if needed).

Comment: You don't need the extra step; you should be able to cast directly to decimal in the Derived Column expression, provided the output column is a *new* column in the data flow: `Flat File -> Derived Column (string to decimal) -> DB Table`.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a better way to do it, But i found a way that works.

Create a Derived Column Expression:
    TRIM(REL_WEIGHT) == "" ? (DT_STR,9,1252)"0.0000000" : (DT_STR,9,1252)(LEFT(REL_WEIGHT,2) + "." + RIGHT(REL_WEIGHT,6))

THEN Create a Data Conversion Task to change it to Numeric and set scale to 6.

And then Map the [Copy of NewField] to my SQL table field set up as Decimal(8,6).

I don't know how the performance will be of that when loading a million records, probably not the best.  If someone knows how to do this in a better way performance wise please let me know.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: There is a better way, which is to convert directly to decimal in the Derived Column transformation. As I said in my answer, you can create a *new* column in the Derived Column transformation. This is done by specifying a new name (different from the original) in the transformation editor. For my example, I had `Last_Update_Time_orig` as the original string column, and the Derived Column transformation created a new column named `Last_Update_Time` from the SSIS expression I copied into my answer. `Last_Update_Time` was what I mapped to the DB table column.

Comment: Here's a good screenshot of the editor: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_3KpWw7vcPX4/S9W0-ayJ7kI/AAAAAAAAAHc/TgqyL6OTLtc/s1600/SSIS2008_expressionEditor_no_coerce-797014.png. Notice the `<add as new column>` text.

Comment: With respect to the data type, IIRC, it is derived automatically from the SSIS expression. Thus, you must get the casts right in the expression, so that the resulting type of the expression is decimal (with the desired scale). Notice how, in my example SSIS expression, I specify `NULL(DT_DBTIME2,0)` as the first alternative of the ternary, and the second alternative has a `(DT_DBTIME2,0)` cast. Thus, both sides are type-consistent, and the entire expression resolves to the time type. You have to do the same thing (but with type `(DT_DECIMAL,6)`) in your expression.

Comment: I tried again to get rid of the data conversion piece and got a conversion error again when trying to input it into the SQL table.  I'll try it again monday.  It's a least working now